# Как добавить элемент в Map через консоль

Tags: golang

Не могу представить, как сделать, чтобы через консоль можно было ввести *ключ* , а после и элемент.

Comment: ваш вопрос равнозначен: "как ввести два значения key, value с консоли?" (`m[key]=value` добавляет элемент в `map`). Очевидно, ответ зависит от типа key, value, формата входных данных. Например, если тип key является int, а число вводится, используя десятичную запись со стандартного ввода, то вы можете задать (отдельный) вопрос: "как прочитать целое число в Go...". Не достаточно информации в вопросе для полного ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for {
        var key string
        var value int
        fmt.Print("Введите ключ: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&key)
        if key == "" {
            break
        }

        for {
            fmt.Print("Введите значение:")
            _, err := fmt.Scanln(&value)
            if err == nil {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        m[key] = value
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m)
}
```